# Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors

Tags: angular, typescript

Though I've added `AuthComponent` to `AuthModule` but, I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'auth' is not a known element:
1. If 'auth' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ystem.import('public/app/auth').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });</script></head><body>[ERROR ->]<auth><div class="progress-container"><div class="progress"><div class="indeterminate"></div></div></"): ng:///success-snackBar.component@0:861 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
```

I've read most of the topics related to this issue(Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors) but, I couldn't solve my problem.

Here is my component:

```
import {Component, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'auth',
    templateUrl: './auth.component.html'
})
export class AuthComponent {
}
```

The login form:

```
<head>
    <script src='systemjs.config.js'></script>
    <script> 
        System.import('public/app/auth').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <auth></auth> // the selector is used here and the error comes from here
</body>
```

AuthModule:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {LoginModule} from "./login/login.module";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {AuthComponent} from "./auth/auth.component";
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        LoginModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AuthComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService
    ],
    exports: [
        AuthComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AuthComponent]
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Bootstrapped `AuthModule` like this:

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {AuthModule} from "./auth.module";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AuthModule);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you bootstrap `AuthModule`? Also `templateUrl: './auth.component'` isn't sound like `templateUrl`, it should be `./auth.component.html'`(.thml extention)

Comment: Yes I bootstrapped `AuthModule`, updated my post.